# Plural form of "semantics"

Tags: grammatical-number

I think the word "semantics" is singular (just like e.g. "mathematics"), at least it is used that way (e.g. "... the semantics of ... "). I know its meaning at least in technical terms and I understand that often it makes sense to "treat it as singular" such as stated [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/semantics). However, I definitively need the plural form and it feels like "semantices" sounds terrible.

edit:

1. I insist that "semantics" is countable in the context at hand. I use "a semantics" as a mathematical term that refers to basically a function that maps strings of symbols to mathematical objects. Those functions are a countable quantity (in the linguistic, not the mathematical meaning of the term).
2. I do understand that "semantics" is already in plural but this doesn't solve the problem at hand because, if what Jon Hanna says is correct, then it "doesnt work for something countable".

Comment: Give us the sentence where you "definitively need the plural form".

Comment: several "semantices" of(for?) our language are introduced in section x.

Comment: What do you mean by ' 
several semantics of(for?) our language are introduced in section x'? Which 
 sense of _semantics_  do you mean? [AHD, Collins etc](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/semantics) offer several.

Comment: 3. (Logic) logic

a. the study of interpretations of a formal theory

Comment: AHD says that either singular or plural agreement is acceptable, though I'd want 'several approaches to / views on the semantics of our language are ...'.

Comment: *"Several semantics of our language"* ... are you sure this is what you want? I would have assumed that a language could have only one *semantics*.

Comment: @Peter Hey, that's _my_ quibble.

Comment: please refer to my edit on why there are different "semantics"

Comment: So,, what is the plural of "mathematics"?

Comment: Same exact problem

Comment: Maybe invent your own... Each of the languages has its own semantics.  But all of these semantixes share some basic features.

Comment: The plural of "semantics" is the unacceptable form "semanticses".

Comment: A little late to the party, but for what it's worth OP, I'm with you. There are certain technical contexts where "semantics" is used as a singular, such as in sentences like "We need to apply a different semantics here". I personally tend to try and rearrange my sentence if at all possible to avoid needing a plural, as others have suggested, but when it's really unavoidable (and sometimes it is), I just use the same word as the plural and let articles, verb tenses, and context handle the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a countable plural corresponding to *a semantics,* just use "two" (three, four, etc) ***semantics.*** Nothing else is possible in terms of a single word (you are correct about "semantices" being awful; the same goes for "semanticses").

Using "semantics" as a countable noun seems jargony to me, but it is [precedented](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+semantics+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20semantics%20are%3B%2Cc0):

[image: Google Ngram showing increasing use of "two semantics are"]

[Google Books "two semantics"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two%20semantics%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

You would do the same thing if you are talking about different kinds of "mathematics" – e.g. "I will discuss two mathematics: the mathematics of X and the mathematics of Y".

Comment: I wonder how many of those ngrams are for "x semantics systems" or the like. I bet that's more common than semantics as the head noun.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I just edited the ngram graph to show "two semantics are" to avoid that problem

Answer (score 3):

Plural form is also "*semantics*" ([source](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/semantics)):

> *Let's not argue about **semantics**.* [uncountable; used with a singular verb]
>
> *The **semantics** of those terms are confusing.* [plural; used with a plural verb]

Comment: So it is correct to write "the two semantics are very different"?

Comment: To me as long as the plural verb is used ("*are*") [it's OK](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22semantics+are+different%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=Me7EWaXxFcyX6ATboIH4DQ).

Comment: @D.F.F. Again, what are you trying to say? 'The two physics are very different' is acceptable (if rare) in some situations.

Comment: Semantics refers to "3. (Logic) logic

a. the study of interpretations of a formal theory". So yes, it is similar to your example with the physics (which again seems odd in singular)

Comment: @D.F.F. No; I was using 'physic' in the old-fashioned 'medicine' count usage.

Answer (score 2):

> I think the word "semantics" is singular (just like e.g. "mathematics")

*Semantics* is plural, just like *mathematics*.

> I understand that often it makes sense to "treat it as singular"

That means that, as with *mathematics* the plural word is often used the way a singular word would be: always *semantics*, never *a semantic*.

> However, I definitively need the plural form.

If you did definitely need the plural form, then you'd be in luck since *semantics* is plural. I'm doubtful as to why you "definitely need the plural form", since that suggests you need it for something countable which it doesn't work for.

> several "semantices" of(for?) our language are introduced in section

I think here you actually need, ironically enough, the singular form.

Consider "*A semantic of our language is introduced". Would you ever use that? I imagine you mean one of the features that semantics studies:

> Several semantic features of our language are introduced in this section.
>
> Several semantic principles of our language are introduced in this section.

Comment: In fact semantics is countable in my case. I introduce four (4) completely different semantics (interpretations) of a formal language. I do not speak about different features of one semantics but of entirely different "ways of interpretation" (I want to use the term semantics for technical reasons).

Comment: Ah, I got you. In the case of "one semantics" you are, as the dictionary you quote says, treating it as singular though the word is (as the dictionary you quote also says) plural.

Comment: No! That is just the problem I am trying to solve ;) I use "semantics" if I speak about one semantics, which I think is correct and I am at peace with. However, I would like to use a word like "semantices" in those cases I speak about several (countable) semantic(e)s. Problem is that such a word doesn't exist.

Comment: So you're saying the dictionary you linked to is wrong, and it's not really plural, but often treated as singular?

Comment: where did I say that?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the comment above. If you want a plural for *semantics* then since *semantics* is already plural, why don't you just use it?

Comment: You said yourself that I cannot use it to refer to a countable quantity, but that is what I need to do. My question is how to solve that exact problem (if possible)

Comment: "A semantic" is a single unit of semantic meaning that could be attached to something. "A semantics" is a scheme of such semantics, generally in an academic or information sciences setting. For instance, here's a philosophical logic paper from 1979 titled, "On When a Semantics is Not a Semantics: Some Reasons for Disliking the Routley-Meyer Semantics for Relevance Logic": https://www.jstor.org/stable/30227176